# Как в аргумент insertAdjacentHTML вставить переменную

Tags: javascript, html

*Есть строка кода, с помощью которой, я могу вывести скрытый текст*

```
result.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", "<div id=block_id style=display: none>Скрытый текст</div>");
```

Вместо **Скрытый текст**, мне нужно вставить таблицу, т.е

```
result.appendChild(table);
```

Вставить **result.appendChild(table)** вместо текста не удаётся, как и засунуть это в переменную.
Просьба помочь!

Comment: второй параметр insertAdjacentHTML - это строка, соответственно и вставить можно только строку.

Comment: @Grundy, чем я могу заменить insertAdjacentHTML, подскажи.

Comment: можно не менять просто вставлять разметку таблицы. Также можно воспользоваться [`insertAdjacentElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentElement) куда передается именно html элемент, а не строка

Comment: @Grundy, Спасибо, сейчас попробую

Comment: @Grundy insertAdjacentElement не подошёл(
Как я могу разметку таблицы вставить, не совсем понимаю..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`.insertAdjacentHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) вторым параметром принимает строку и если вставляется простой html элемент без каких либо обработчиков событий - достаточно взять его [`.outerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML) и вставить значение в собираемую строку, например с помощью [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

```
result.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", `<div id='block_id' style='display: none'>${table.outerHTML}</div>`);
```

---

Либо добавить сначала пустой элемент

```
result.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", `<div id='block_id' style='display: none'></div>`);
```

затем выбрать его и добавить с помощью [`appendChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild)

```
document.getElementById('block_id').appendChild(table)
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, я использовал второй вариант)